# Sudo Python doesn't work

Tags: python

I am able to invoke python 3.3.0 using my alias, in .bashrc, python3.3. But sudo python3.3 doesn't work.

Error is : Python command not found.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

bash only checks the first word for aliases. If the first word is an alias(which expands to something that ends with a space), it also checks the next word for aliases. So you can:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

in your `.bashrc`.

Comment: There are no spaces in alias. It is python3.3